# is there a way to block the raycast in ui?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have three sliders to control the object rotation, however when I slide it the camera is rotated too. is there a way to block the raycast at ui?

[image]

```
 void movecam()
    {
        turn.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        turn.y +=  Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-turn.y,turn.x,0);
     
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your code for rotating the camera?

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick, Add a "Raycast Target Enabled" panel behind it

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are moving the camera with your mouse movement. One thing you can do is check if mouse is over UI element, don't move camera. You can do this using `IsPointerOverGameObject()` method.

```
void movecam()
{
     bool isOverUI = UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject();
     if(!isOverUI){
        turn.x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        turn.y +=  Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-turn.y,turn.x,0);
     }

 }
```